# I'd like to see if worksheet exists and Select the worksheet but "Argument not Optional" appears

Tags: vba, excel

```
    If CheckSheet() = True Then
        Worksheet.Select
    End If

Function CheckSheet(ByVal SheetName As String) As Boolean

    Dim Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim bReturn As Boolean

    For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
       If Sheet.Name = SheetName Then
           bReturn = True
           Exit For
       End If
   Next Sheet

   CheckSheet = bReturn
End Function
```

Compile Error:
Argument Not Optional

Then CheckSheet is highlighted after pressing Ok

Comment: The missing argument is `ByVal SheetName As String`. You have to provide the name of the sheet you're looking for. E.g. `If CheckSheet("Sheet 1") = True`

Comment: Your `CheckSheet` function wants a string to be passed to it.  You aren't.  Do so, and it will work.  You will then need to fix the next line, unless you have a `Worksheet` object which you have called `Worksheet`.  Hopefully you haven't, so it is more likely meant to be `Worksheets("someWorksheetName").Select`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
If CheckSheet() = True Then
        Worksheet.Select
End If
```

calls a function with parameters, as this line shows:

```
Function CheckSheet(ByVal SheetName As String) As Boolean
```

Try this instead:

```
Dim wsName as String
wsName = "YourWorksheetName"

If CheckSheet(wsName) = True Then
            Sheets(wsName).Select
End If
```

Edit: As @YowE3K pointed out, your `.Select` statement needs to know the sheet in question as well. Changed `Worksheet.Select` to `Sheets("YourSheetName").Select`

Comment: I can't specify just one sheet cause I'm checking through all the worksheets in the active workbook if that sheet exists. What argument should I put?

Comment: @HydesYase - What is the name of the sheet you are checking for?  Put that as the parameter instead of "YourSheetName" in David's example.

Comment: @HydesYase - The parameter is the name of the sheet you are checking for, it does not specify the sheet you are checking it against. In fact, you still loop through all the sheets.